# netstandard 2.0 package is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 project

Tags: .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I created a nuget package which one of my "netcoreapp2.2" projects references.

The nuspec for the package supports multiple frameworks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <description>Description</description>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0">
        <dependency id="Dapper.StrongName" version="1.50.5" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="Dapper.StrongName" version="1.50.5" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\net452\MyPackage.dll" target="lib\net40\" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net452\MyPackage.pdb" target="lib\net40\" />
    <file src="bin\Release\netstandard2.0\MyPackage.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0\" />
    <file src="bin\Release\netstandard2.0\MyPackage.pdb" target="lib\netstandard2.0\" />
  </files>
</package>
```

As my app is a "netcoreapp2.2" app, I would expect it to be happy referencing a "netstandard2.0" package, but I get this error:

```
Package MyPackage 1.0.20191009.9 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2). Package MyPackage 1.0.20191009.9 supports:
[15:37:55][restore]       - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
[15:37:55][restore]       - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

Am I missing something in my nuspec to tell it that this netstandard2.0 package is compatible with netcoreapp2.2?

Comment: Is there anything else peculiar in your project file? This is an odd one.

Comment: How are you restoring?  If by any chance you're using an old version of nuget.exe, maybe that version doesn't know about netcoreapp2.2, so doesn't know what versions of netstandard it's compatible with. If all projects in your solution/repo are SDK style, I recommend `dotnet restore` instead of `nuget restore`.

Comment: Did you maybe figure this out?